# Error "There are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request"

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, windows-xp, login

I am the guy that was closest to the server :( and am actually a developer. I am getting the following error when a machine on the domain is trying to be accessed from other machines from the network:

> There are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request

Accessing other machines from this machine works as expected.

How should I go about to fix this?

We are running a Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP Professional clients.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got it fixed by unjoining from the domain on the machine and removed it from Active Directory. Then rejoined the machine back onto the domain and now everything works again.

When looking at the Active directory record for the machine, it did not look right in some ways compared to the others. For example, the operating system was not set - the description and fields like these.

Answer (score 3):

"Have you tried turning it off an on again?" :)

No. Really. This seems to be a network messup where your client doesn't see the domain controllers. Maybe there's something wrong with DNS or IP addressing, or anything else preventing proper communication between Client and DCs.

Answer (score 2):

This happens on our Windows 7 laptops if not directly connected to the network after we install software onto them or do a Windows update. Is random but happens after updates often. Connecting the laptop to the physical LAN corrects the issue until the next update/software installation.