# There are currently no logon servers available

Tags: security, windows-7, active-directory, remote-access

I am running a Windows 7 laptop that is joined to my company's domain. When I installed Windows 7, I created an account for myself, joined to the domain, and it had been working quite well even though I'm physically remote most of the time, and not actually on the network.

However, today I created a new local user account (non-admin) for my little brother. While he was using it, he decided he wanted to install a program, because his account is not an admin, he was prompted to enter Administrator credentials to allow the program to make changes to his computer. I entered my credentials, and this is the first time I ran into the error message:

> There are currently no logon servers
>   available to service the logon
>   request.

I tried logging off and loggin back in, rebooting, etc etc, and no matter what, every time I try to authenticate as my "normal" domain account - I get that message.

**I can no longer access my computer as an administrator. I no longer know how to log in to my machine using any other account aside from my little brother's non-admin account.**

I don't have any other local accounts created, and the default local admin account was never enabled.

I'd appreciate any ideas on how I can recover access to my account. Let me know if I can provide any more information.

FYI - This is a similar question but not sure any of the answers help me in my case. [Error "There are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request"](https://serverfault.com/questions/71632/there-are-currently-no-logon-servers-available-to-service-the-logon-request)

Comment: You should discuss this with your system administrator.

Comment: User ".\administrator" as the username. Default is domain admin, which is not available. <computername>\<name> oder just ".\" for 'local' will fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd hazzard a guess that it's related to cached credentials... when you created the new user and logged in as it, you "wiped" the cached creds for your domain account. I suspect that the "fix" would be to connect to your work LAN again - then a DC would be available to authenticate you, and the cached creds would be restored - but it'd probably break again the next time your brother logged in....

It does kinda beg the question - are your IT peeps happy with you creating local logins for family members on your work kit? I know **I** wouldn't look kindly on my users trying this!! ;-)

Just my $0.02...

Comment: I think you're right on with the cached credentials. I'm sure if I was available to login while actually on the domain I wouldn't have ever had a problem. Unfortunately that presents a bit of a challenge when you're physically nowhere near the LAN....

As for whether they're happy with it - I guess it won't matter because when I did a restore it wiped out the new account and I'm not going to try it again :)

Answer (score 1):

If the remote computer is a part of a domain, then you must include the computer name with the user Id, or it will assume the Id is from the domain, and go looking for a logon server to authenticate it!

So, when entering your credentials, be sure to include your computer name with the user id. If you computer is "Home1" and your local id is "Ian", then enter your Id as "Home1\Ian".

This also applies to connecting a drive to a remote computer, using a local Id on that remote computer... so:

```
net use z: \\192.168.0.100\sharedFolder /user:home1\ian *
```

(The * at the end of the line tells the computer to ask you for the password, so you don't have to type it where everyone can see it.)

Answer (score 0):

I've indirectly resolved the problem - I was able to do a system restore from two days ago and get logged back in as myself. The new user that I had created is no longer there. I'm hesitant to create it again - however I did enable my local Admin account and create another restore point again just in case.

Comment: For the record, I'm still curious to know what exactly changed when I created a new local user and logged in as that user - why would it screw up my domain account? If anyone has any ideas please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I never faced this problems as you did.Whenever I created a new user, it works perfect.Can you find some clues on Microsoft website or from their technical engineer directly?