# Remote user cannot login to computer - There are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request

Tags: windows-7, essentials-2012-r2

So i am having an issue very similar to the issue described [On this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/103655/there-are-currently-no-logon-servers-available)

A laptop user in the company was joined into the domain and was able to work both locally (with the network cable plugged in) and remotely (from WiFi in different places using OpenVPN).

The user has now left the country and cannot log in to he's computer.
He is getting the **"there are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request"** error message and cannot log in to the laptop.

There are no other users on the laptop except the domain user.

My Question(s):

1. How can this be fixed without having the user to return the laptop?
2. Since no other users on that computer, what could have happened to the Cached credentials?

If you need any more details, Please feel free to ask, i will be grateful for any help i can get on this, i really don't want to tell my supervisors that the laptop needs to be sent from UK back to Hungary just to connect it back to the network.

Comment: Nothing? No one can help with this?

Comment: Is the domain-user in the list of local admins for this laptop ?

Comment: he should be, since he was admin before he joined the domain (but i did delete he's local account after the join).

Comment: Has he tried booting in safe mode?

Comment: What would be the difference? (asking to know)

Comment: Just speculation, but maybe he has a disabled built-in admin account; safe-mode would enable the account

Comment: The user is a "dumb" user, he hardly knows to use skype and outlook, Hard for me to believe he might have disabled the admin account.

Comment: If he was the first local user created, the built-in Administrator account will have the same password unless you changed/disabled it

Comment: The built-in admin account is disabled by default, as far as I can remember. Leaving an unexperienced user as sole admin of a machine is a daring feat, though :9

Comment: @JannisAlexakis - i agree, the build-in admin account is disabled by default, why do you find that daring? each user has he's personal laptop and the domain administrator can log-in anyway (if he had connection to that computer :P )

Comment: It´s a matter of the individual grade of paranoia, but I don´t give local admin rights to company laptop users, with few exceptions. I always create a local admin account with credentials known only to me.

Comment: Speculating here, maybe the UK has blocked VPN services, and when he is trying to authenticate it can not find the domain controller because it isn't connected through VPN.

Comment: @Travis - he cannot logon to windows, therfor cannot dial in.

Comment: @Dementic OpenVPN can be started prior to login (on the CTRL-ALT-DEL screen) and allow you to connect to a VPN connection prior to actual login.  This way you actually authenticate to the domain.

Comment: @Travis could you point me to instructions?

Comment: https://forums.openvpn.net/topic8854.html OR https://forums.openvpn.net/topic7130.html